# validations for aadhar,pancard,voterid using express and nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, postman

what are the validations we can do with nodejs,express with aadhar,pancard?

when we enter the add user route the aadhar,pancard and voter id should validate based on nodejs

I am expecting the  validations we do  like how many validations using nodejs

Comment: Its confidential data. Only government websites have this data access only they can verify these. You can go to government website to verify.